Support for Managing IPs on Vercel and MongoDB OVH
I need your help.
I'm building a new service and, for now, I am using the free plan of Vercel (but I will upgrade to Pro within July). I am using Atlas MongoDB as the database service, but I want to switch to MongoDB provided by OVH (to meet the requirements of my biggest prospect who wants to use my service as soon as it is released). OVH requires a list of IPs to allow connections, so I need to know how Vercel manages the IPs of deployed services (do they change with every deploy? Where can I see the IP's value for a specific deploy?).
Thanks to everyone.

There are no fixed IPs for Vercel, given the nature of the underlying infrastructure: https://vercel.com/guides/can-i-get-a-fixed-ip-address
